# Opencart Version 2.3.0.2, Unable to load success page

Tags: opencart

I am using opencart 2.3.0.2 latest version , i have created custom payment module in this , by using this , i am unable to load success page.
below is controller file..

```
$response = $client->Operation($params);

$response_value=$response->OperationResult->ResultData;
$result_array=$response->OperationResult->ResultCode;
$transation_number=$response->OperationResult->TransactionNumber;
$xml_error=explode(":",$response->OperationResult->AdditionalInfo);

$json = array();
if(isset($xml_error['2'])){
    $payment_error=$xml_error['2'];
}else{
    $payment_error="";
}

if($payment_error == ''){

    $response_value = $response->OperationResult->ResultData;
    if($result_array == '0'){
        $report = "Transaction Id:".$transation_number;

        $this->model_checkout_order->addOrderHistory($this->session->data['order_id'], $this->config->get('config_order_status_id'),$report, false);
        $message = $response_value;

        $this->model_checkout_order->addOrderHistory($this->session->data['order_id'], $this->config->get('config_order_status_id'), $message, FALSE);

        $json['redirect'] = $this->url->link('checkout/success');

    }else{
        $json['error'] = $response_value;
    }
}else{
    $json['error'] = $payment_error;
}

$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
```

and below is my ajax request  method

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#creditcard_payment input[type=\'radio\']:checked,#creditcard_payment input[type=\'text\'],#creditcard_payment input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked,#creditcard_payment input[type=\'hidden\'],#creditcard_payment select'),
    url: 'index.php?route=extension/payment/cnp/confirm',
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#button-confirm').button('loading');
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#button-confirm').button('reset');
    },      
    success: function(json) {
        alert('test');
        if (json['error']) {
            alert(json['error']);
        }
        if (json['redirect']) {
            alert(json['redirect']);
            location = json['redirect'];
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: please  tell us too that what  error you are getting ? , also check from the console if you are getting correct response.

Comment: I am not getting response, Response empty in console ..

Comment: ajax call is working ? ?

Comment: yes ajax call also working , when i see console log , the response page in display like html in console , only not able to redirect success page.

Comment: try `window.location`   instead `location`

Comment: tried but not working

Comment: i m ubale to reply on this chat room because i dont have reputation points , required minimum 20 points

Answer (score 0):

if you want to `JSON` response then add `dataType` to `AJAX` option. as follow.

```js
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'index.php?route=extension/payment/cnp/confirm',
    dataType: 'JSON', // need to add for JSON responce.
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#creditcard_payment input[type=\'radio\']:checked,#creditcard_payment input[type=\'text\'],#creditcard_payment input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked,#creditcard_payment input[type=\'hidden\'],#creditcard_payment select'),
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#button-confirm').button('loading');
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#button-confirm').button('reset');
    },      
    success: function(json) {
        alert('test');
        if (json['error']) {
            alert(json['error']);
        }
        if (json['redirect']) {
            alert(json['redirect']);
            location = json['redirect'];
        }
    }
});
```

and if you directly use JSON to ajax then don't use response output. This is because many modules use this response output function as needed, like minify, replace etc.

just replace last two line of controller.

```
$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
```

TO

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
die;
```